# How to remove python 3.7.3 from Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I have Python 3.7.3 on my mac which I would like to remove.
The guides say to move the python app to trash from applications but it is not even there. The guides also say to remove it from the Library folder. going into frameworks/Python.Framework but I can not see the folder. Also, When I am using the terminal for this sequence:

```
a-MacBook-Pro:~ a$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
a-MacBook-Pro:~ a$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 a  admin  34 Jun  2 17:34 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.3/bin/python3
```

which makes me understand that the file is in the Cellar folder and not Library?

How can I remove it so that when I write python3 --version I am notified that not python3 is installed?

Comment: Probably `brew uninstall python3` or something, because it looks like you installed it with Homebrew and not the Python installer.

Comment: If it's in the `Cellar` directory it must have been installed using `brew`. Try `brew uninstall python3`

Comment: Yeah thats what happened, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you have installed python3 with Homebrew, you can uninstall it with:

```
 brew uninstall python3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used homebrew to install Python, you can do this.,

```
brew uninstall python3
```

Use this for a specific Python version.,

```
brew uninstall python@3.7
```

**OR**

Alternatively You may uninstall by.,

1. To remove the framework, enter the following:

   **sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7**
2. Remove the app directory:

   **sudo rm -rf “/Applications/Python 3.7”**
3. Ensure that the symbolic links in /usr/local/bin exit with the following command:

   **ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep ‘../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7’**